# java program to divide an image file into 4 parts

Tags: java

I want to divide an image file into 4 parts using java i tried it but i am getting exceptions and also i want to store all the pixel values of image into an array. for this i used pixel grabber class but of no use.please help me

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [this](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/#13)?

Answer (score -1):

javax.imageio.ImageIO.read() returns a BufferedImage. I think that should be useful.